# onHover is not responding to onHover action

Tags: swiftui

I have this simple code

```
import SwiftUI

struct testv: View {
    @State private var isHover = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hover test")
            .foregroundColor(isHover ? .green : .red)
            .onHover { hovering in
                isHover = hovering
            }
    }
}

struct testv_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        testv()
    }
}
```

I also tested put the code in different elements like a vstack or hstack and the result is the same, also tested don simulator and at real device

When I hover the element the color of the background is not changing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.onHover` works only on iPadOS/macOS and only if

- you enable *Set Pointer to Device* in the I/O menu of the iPad simulator.
- a mouse is connected to the device.